# How to change EMS SQL Manager view from 'like Delphi' to 'like MS Office'?

Tags: delphi, interface, view

The installer proposed me to choose more convinient view: like in Delphi or like in MS Office.
I chose Delphi, but now I want to change it. And I cant find how to do it. Is is possible?

Answer (score 1):

Ah.. the only way I've found was to manually delete all EMS information from Windows registry. After that I've seen window with view-settings again and have chosen Office-like view.